# How to create Laravel 5.1 Custom Authentication driver?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working in Laravel authentication login using socialite. Now I can able to save data of user from socialite. But now I am facing problem how to authenticate user from gmail, github.

After some research I understood that I need to create custom authentication. I googled but all are Laravel 4.1 topics. If any one work on this please provide your answers.

I already read following topics but I didn't got how to do it?

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver

http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5

Update

```
public function handleProviderCallback() {
    $user = Socialite::with('github')->user();
    $email=$user->email;
    $user_id=$user->id;

    //$authUser = User::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('email', $email)->first();
    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    if(Auth::login($authUser, true)) {
        return Redirect::to('user/UserDashboard');
    }   
}

private function findOrCreateUser($user) {
    if ($authUser = User::where('user_id',$user->id)->first()) {
        return $authUser;
    }

    return User::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->nickname,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'avatar' => $user->avatar
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to create custom authentication? Socialite has drivers for both Google and GitHub.

Comment: @MartinBean.i am new to laravel.i can able to save data but now i am facing problem how i can authenticate

Answer (score 17):

> This answer is most suited for Laravel 5.1. Please take care if you
>   are in some other version. Also keep in mind that IMHO this is a rather advanced level in Laravel, and hence if you don't fully understand what you are doing, you may end up crashing your application. The solution is not end to end correct. This is just a general guideline of what you need to do in order for this to work.

### Adding Custom Authentication Drivers In Laravel 5.1

**Hint:** Laravel documentation for this topic is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#adding-custom-authentication-drivers).

**Hint2:** The last link you mentioned is quite useful in my opinion. I learned all of this after reading that link.

http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5

---

Before we start, I would first like to describe the login flow which will help you understand the process. Laravel uses a `driver` to connect to the database to fetch your records. Two drivers come pre-bundled with laravel - `eloquent` & `database`. We want to create a third so that we can customize it to our needs.

`Illuminate\Auth\Guard` inside your vendor folder is the main file which has code for the user to log in and log out. And this file mainly uses two `Contracts (or interfaces)` that we need to override in order for our driver to work. From Laravel's own documentation read this:

> The Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider implementations are only
>   responsible for fetching a Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
>   implementation out of a persistent storage system, such as MySQL,
>   Riak, etc. These two interfaces allow the Laravel authentication
>   mechanisms to continue functioning regardless of how the user data is
>   stored or what type of class is used to represent it.

So the idea is that for our driver to work we need to implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` and `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` and tell Laravel to use these implementations instead of the defaults.

---

**So let's begin.**

**`Step 1:`**
Choose a name for your driver. I name mine `socialite`. Then in your `config/auth.php`, change the `driver` name to `socialite`. By doing this we just told laravel to use this driver for authentication instead of `eloquent` which is default.

**`Step 2:`**
In your `app/Provider/AuthServiceProvider` in the `boot()` method add the following lines:

```
Auth::extend('socialite', function($app) {
    $provider = new SocialiteUserProvider();
    return new AuthService($provider, App::make('session.store'));
});
```

What we did here is:

- We first used `Auth` facade to define the `socialite` driver.
- `SocialiteUserProvider` is an implementation of `UserProvider`.
- `AuthService` is my extension of `Guard` class. The second parameter this class's constructor takes is the session which laravel uses to get and set sessions.
- So we basically told Laravel to use our own implementation of `Guard` class instead of the default one.

**`Step 3:`**
Create `SocialiteUserProvider`. If you read the Laravel's documentation, you will understand what each of these methods should return. I have created the first method as a sample. As you can see, I use my `UserService` class to fetch results. You can fetch your own results however you want to fetch them. Then I created an `User` object out of it. This `User` class implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` contract.

```
<?php
namespace App\Extensions;

use App\User;
use App\Services\UserService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class SocialiteUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    private $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        $result = $this->userService->getUserByEmail($identifier);
        if(count($result) === 0)
        {
            $user = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $user = new User($result[0]);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }
}
```

**`Step 4:`**
Create `User` class which implements the `Authenticatable`. This class has to implement this interface because the `Guard` class will use this class to get values.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements Authenticatable
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'userEmail';
    protected $attributes = [];

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    public function getUserAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->attributes[$this->primaryKey];
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // Implement your own.
    }
}
```

**`Step 5:`**
Finally create the AuthService class that will call the `Guard` methods. This is my own implementation. You can write your own as per your needs. What we have done here is extended the `Guard` class to implement two new functions which are self explanatory.

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;

class AuthService extends Guard
{
    public function signin($email)
    {
        $credentials = array('email' => $email);
        $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, false, true);
        $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveById($email);

        if($user !== null)
        {
            $this->login($user, false);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function signout()
    {
        $this->clearUserDataFromStorage();

        if(isset($this->events))
        {
            $this->events->fire('auth.logout', [$this->user()]);
        }

        $this->user = null;
        $this->loggedOut = true;
    }
}
```

**`Step 6: Bonus Step`**
Just to complete my answer, I will also explain the structure that `UserService` class expects. First lets understand what this class does. In our above steps we created everything to let laravel know how to use our authentication driver, instead of theirs. But we still haven't told laravel that how should it get the data. All we told laravel that if you call the `userService->getUserByEmail($email)` method, you will get your data. So now we simply have to implement this function.

**E.g.1 You are using `Eloquent`.**

```
public function getUserByEmail($email)
{
    return UserModel::where('email', $email)->get();
}
```

**E.g.2 You are using `Fluent`.**

```
public function getUserByEmail($email)
{
    return DB::table('myusertable')->where('email', '=', $email)->get();
}
```

## Update: 19 Jun 2016

Thank you @skittles for pointing out that I have not clearly shown **where the files should be placed.** All the files are to be placed as per the namespace given. E.g. if the namespace is `App\Extensions` and the class name is `SocialiteUserProvider` then location of file is `App\Extensions\SocialiteUserProvider.php`. The `App` directory in laravel is the `app` folder.

Comment: could you please show us your UserService class? that is the only thing missing from making your answer a complete one.

Comment: @LastTemplar Hello. I have updated my answer that should fit your needs. Unfortunately, I could not add my own UserService class because I use several layers of code to get my data. I use repository pattern. But for you it should be as I have shown in my example. Please let me know if you need some more info. Happy coding!

Comment: @Rash - Your advice might have far more value if you were WAY more specific about where each file lives that you say to create. This is seriously horrible if you provide help that causes the reader far more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Skittles Thanks for you suggestion. However, could you be more specific where you think more changes are needed? As per PSR4 standards, the namespace indicates where the files need to be. This is also the default laravel project structure, so things should be self explanatory here. I would love if you could point out where more information is needed and I will consider the changes.

Comment: @Rash - I guess that there are those of us that have yet to understand the "self explanatory" nature of what you're referring to. I, for instance, have never heard the term PSR4. Equally, I was not aware that namespaces had anything to do with file locations. So, when you;re giving advice, perhaps assume that the audience that will be reading it will not always be on your level.

Comment: @Skittles That was a fair point. I have updated my answer with an update at the bottom of my answer. `PSR4` is a PHP coding standard that people are now implementing in their code. Things like what should your file name be, where should it be placed, use spaces instead of tabs, and other things like that.

Comment: @Rash - Thank you, Rash!

Comment: Is it also true for laravel 5.4. I tried a lot, but this approach does not work on laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Good tutorial for setting up laravel socialite here: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/using-github-authentication-for-login-with-laravel-socialite

[`Auth::login`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_login) doesn't return a boolean value you can use attempt to do a `Auth::attempt`

```
if(Auth::login($authUser, true)) {
    return Redirect::to('user/UserDashboard');
}
```

Follow the tutorial and do this, and just have middleware configured on the home route

```
$authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

Auth::login($authUser, true);

return Redirect::to('home');
```

Comment: @nathanmac.it will return blank page after login